# List of mp3 files on android device .net maui

Tags: android, maui

I want to make music player for android, but i have problem with getting list of sounds on device. How i can get the list of mp3 files on android device, using .net maui?

I tried to get list in this way:

```
        List<String> list = new List<String>();
        foreach (var file in Directory.GetFiles("/storage/emulated/0/music"))
        {
            list.Add(file);
            flabel.Text = list[0];
        }
```

but I have encountered a mistake: **Access to the path '/storage/emulated/0/music' is denied**
after that, I tried to give the application rights to work with memory in the device, but it did not help. Please help me, there is very little information on this subject on the Internet

Comment: you have to use the Android media apis, you can't just read from the file system

Comment: `I tried to give the application rights to work with memory in the device, but it did not help.`   What exactly did you do? What is the specific problem? Can you elaborate on that?

Comment: @JessieZhang-MSFT I have given the right to memory in the phone settings for my application, but when I try to get files from the directory as above, I get an error: "Access to the path '/storage/emulated/0/music' is denied".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the storage you accessed(`/storage/emulated/0/music`),we could find that you want to access the `external storage`.

To access the external storage, we need to add the external storage permissions as follows:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

And we also need to add [runtime permission](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/permissions?tabs=windows) after Android 6.0 (API level 23).

And there is an official sample here about how to access external storage, you can check it here: [local files](https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples/tree/main/LocalFiles).

For more information, you can check: [External storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/files/external-storage?tabs=windows).